# Android Ringtone over Content Provider

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac

i want to set a ringtone from my asset Folder as a default ringtone. Now i found, that this is not possible, because asset isn't accessable from outside. So i must go the way to copy the file from my asset to sd or i use a content Provider. The last i think is the better way.

But I don't get it to work, I hope you can help me. Here is my Content Provider:

```
public class ringtoneContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String TAG = "ringtoneCP";
    private static String[] mimeTypes = {"audio/ogg"};
    private Uri generatedUri;

    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Log.d("provider", "Provider openAssetFile wird aufgerufen");
        AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
        String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if(file_name == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = am.openFd(file_name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return afd;//super.openAssetFile(uri, mode);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType( Uri p1 )
    {
        Log.d("provider","provider getType");
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return "audio/ogg";
    }

    @Override
    public int delete( Uri p1, String p2, String[] p3 )
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        throw new RuntimeException("ContentProvider.delete not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query( Uri p1, String[] p2, String p3, String[] p4, String p5 )
    {
        Log.d("provider","provider query 1");
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query( Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal )
    {
        Log.d("provider","provider query 2");
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return super.query( uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder, cancellationSignal );
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert( Uri p1, ContentValues p2 )
    {
        Log.d("provider","provider insert");
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate( )
    {
        Log.d("provider","provider onCreate");
        generatedUri = Uri.EMPTY;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getStreamTypes(Uri uri, String mimeTypeFilter) {
        Log.d("provider","provider getStreamTypes");
        return mimeTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public int update( Uri p1, ContentValues p2, String p3, String[] p4 )
    {
        Log.d("provider","provider update");
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return 0;
    }
}
```

an here I want to set the Ringtone:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                getApplicationContext(),
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                Uri.parse("content://com.xyz.ringtoneContentProvider/ringtone.ogg")
        );
```

But this doesn't work. So I do this:

```
Uri myFile = Uri.parse("content://com.xyz.ringtoneContentProvider/ringtone.ogg");

//We now create a new content values object to store all the information
//about the ringtone.
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
//values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, myFile.getPath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "MyRingtone"); // file.getName());
//values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST, getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);

//Work with the content resolver now
//First get the file we may have added previously and delete it,
//otherwise we will fill up the ringtone manager with a bunch of copies over time.
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(myFile.toString());
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + myFile + "\"", null);


//Ok now insert it
Uri newUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(myFile, values);

//Ok now set the ringtone from the content manager's uri, NOT the file's uri
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
        getApplicationContext(),
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
        newUri
);
```

But this didn't work either.

---

### ------------- With Stream Provider -------------

With the Steam Provider I get the following error if i open the Settings App / Sound:

```
The exact Error Message is: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider uri content://com.xyz.myStreamProvider/ringtone.ogg from pid=1446, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
            at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:467)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:394)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:194)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

If I do android:exported="true" and android:grantUriPermissions="true" I get this Error Message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xyz.app, PID: 1515
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported
            at com.commonsware.cwac.provider.StreamProvider.attachInfo(StreamProvider.java:65)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4790)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What could I do?

Comment: Have you tried using [StreamProvider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider)? It wraps the support library's [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and provides `content://` style URIs for assets.

Comment: Looks good, but I don't know, how can I use it? I don't understand the Demo.

Comment: Ok, I get it to run. But now I get permission errors. First I get from RingtoneManager that the provider set to grantUriPermissions to ture and exported = true. But when I do that, I get the error from the Provider Provider must not be exported. So what should I do?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm facing almost the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866201/cant-play-a-ringtone-from-a-contentprovider

Comment: Yes and No. It is not possible to get a Ringtone from the Asset Folder. You must copy it first to an external Storage

Comment: @Burner i was able to serve the file from the asset folder only for contact's ringtones without copying it to an external storage, but not for the phone ringtone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not going to be possible with `StreamProvider` (or Android's `FileProvider`), as both are limited to the case where the request for the stream is initiated by an activity, where you can use `FLAG_GRANT_URI_READ_PERMISSION` to allow selective access to the content. You are welcome to fork `StreamProvider` to lift this restriction.

However, then you will run into the problem that media players will tend to want a seekable stream, which is not possible from an asset served via `StreamProvider`.

Your options are:

1. Copy the file to external storage.
2. Copy the file to internal storage, and use a forked version of `FileProvider` or `StreamProvider` that lifts the must-not-be-exported restriction, as streams backed by simple files are seekable when served by `FileProvider` or `StreamProvider`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is possible with the raw Folder?

Comment: @Burner: No, that is no different than assets from the standpoint of `StreamProvider` and its consumers.